# How to query HTMLElementTagNameMap

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I've got a `ts.Program` and string like 'my-component'. Some of the source files have declarations like `declare global { interface HTMLElementTagNameMap { 'my-component': MyComponent } }`. Starting with just the string 'my-component', is there a way to query the program's type checker directly to get the type for `MyComponent`? Or do I need to visit nodes in each source file and make my own map?

The project webcomponent-analyzer does it the second way (https://github.com/runem/web-component-analyzer/blob/1a71064c66a38923aab783e3885feefccfd19589/src/analyze/flavors/custom-element/discover-definitions.ts#L75):

```
if (ts.isInterfaceDeclaration(node) && ["HTMLElementTagNameMap", "ElementTagNameMap"].includes(node.name.text)) {
    const extensions = getInterfaceKeys(node, { ts, checker });
    return extensions.map(({ key, keyNode, identifier, declaration }) => ({
        tagName: key,
        tagNameNode: keyNode,
        identifierNode: identifier,
        declarationNode: declaration
    }));
}
```

Comment: Just wrote up an answer to your TypeScript question, but saw that the question was unfortunately already deleted. Anyway, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIB4AqA+ZBvAKGWLgC58AjcgIS2wF8DGDRJZEVaAtXQ45BOTwATcl3oBuJgRbho8JMgBiAexX4iyGGqFlKQwcgDOYKKADm9K1OIU4UchjwRyIAK4BbCtHrYpzMABPAAcUADkIEwhhTBCILAAaZABVZAgAD0gQYSNjUwsAbQBdXABeFLTMiGzcgtAYaGUkgDpW+saAJSLNYgB+ZUqsnOQAawhAlRhkTB7+PuQOwerhkzMQc2LkfoiomLisAqUipI7cckxD7rm51wgAN2hZ86kCINDkAA1kcp3IPdD0KoVEkCgBybQqUFJUFwKHIUEUOGghCgkqvOLIACa32Qv2isQBQJBCPsSNh0MRJSAA) it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I need to visit nodes in each source file and make my own map?

Yes, you will need to visit each source file (`program.getSourceFiles()` and filter for the relevant files), then traverse all the nodes finding `'my-component'` properties.

At the current moment and from my understanding, there's barely any way to query the type checker to resolve information without first working from the nodes.

Comment: What about transforming the AST to add an expression that will have the type I'm after and getting the type from that newly-created node? Could that work as a way to query the type checker in some cases?